# Small error I can't figure out

Tags: c#, authentication, scope, registration

Got one tiny error and for the love of me I don't know why:

> Error 1   The name 'email' does not exist in the current context  C:\Users\Janco\Desktop\New folder\Espresso Studio's C\Espresso Studio's C\Espresso Studio's C\Form1.cs  135 69  Espresso Studio's C

The Error is located at :

```
        public string HashPass(string password)
        {
            SHA256 sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

            //compute hash from the bytes of text
            sha.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password + email));    // Error occurs here at email.
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Espresso_Studio_s_C
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tabPage2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void loginsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.loginsBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.loginsDataSet);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'loginsDataSet.Logins' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.loginsTableAdapter.Fill(this.loginsDataSet.Logins);

        }

        private void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddUser(registerUserName.Text, registerPassword.Text, registerConfirmPassword.Text, registerEmail.Text);
        }





        private void AddUser(string username, string password, string confirmPass, string email)
{
    //Local variables to hold values
    string smtpEmail = smtpUserNameTextBox.Text;
    string smtpPassword = smtpPasswordTextBox.Text;
    int smtpPort = (int)smtpPortNumericUD.Value;
    string smtpAddress = smtpAddressTextBox.Text;

    //Regex for making sure Email is valid
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
    Match match = regex.Match(email);

    //Loop through Logins Table
    foreach (DataRow row in loginsDataSet.Logins)
    {
        //And look for matching usernames
        if (row.ItemArray[0].Equals(username))
        {
            //If one is found, show message:
            MessageBox.Show("Username already exists");
            return;
        }
    }

    //Confirm pass must equal password.
    if (password != confirmPass)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match");
    }
    //Password must be at least 8 characters long
    else if (password.Length < 8)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Password must be at least 8 characters long");
    }
    //If email is NOT valid
    else if (!match.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email");
    }
    //If there is no username
    else if (username == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Must have Username");
    }
    //If all is well, create the new user!
    else
    {
        loginsDataSet.LoginsRow newUserRow = loginsDataSet.Logins.NewLoginsRow();

        string EncryptedPass = HashPass(password);
        newUserRow.Username = username;
        newUserRow.Password = EncryptedPass;
        newUserRow.Email = email;

        loginsDataSet.Logins.Rows.Add(newUserRow);
        registerUserName.Text = String.Empty;
        registerPassword.Text = String.Empty;
        registerConfirmPassword.Text = String.Empty;
        registerEmail.Text = String.Empty;
        MessageBox.Show("Thank you for Registering!");
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(smtpEmail) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(smtpPassword) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(smtpAddress) || smtpPort <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Email configuration is not set up correctly! \nCannot sent email!");

        }
        else
        {
            SendMessage(email.ToString(), username.ToString(), password.ToString());
        }
    }
}

        public string HashPass(string password)
        {
            SHA256 sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

            //compute hash from the bytes of text
            sha.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password + email));    // Error occurs here

            //get hash result after compute it
            byte[] result = sha.Hash;

            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                //change it into 2 hexadecimal digits
                //for each byte
                strBuilder.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            return strBuilder.ToString();
        }

        public void SendMessage(string ToAddress, string ToName, string password)
        {

            var client = new SmtpClient(smtpAddressTextBox.Text, (int)smtpPortNumericUD.Value)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUserNameTextBox.Text, smtpPasswordTextBox.Text),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            client.Send(smtpUserNameTextBox.Text, ToAddress, "Thank You!", "Thank you for registering with us today! \n Your username/passwords are: \n \nUsername: "
                                                                        + ToName.ToString() + "\nPassword: " + password.ToString());
        }

        private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Locals to hold values
            string username = loginUserName.Text;
            string password = HashPass(loginPassword.Text);


            //Loop through database
            foreach (DataRow row in loginsDataSet.Logins)
            {
                //And search for Username and Pass that match
                if (row.ItemArray[0].Equals(username) && row.ItemArray[1].Equals(password))
                {
                    loginUserName.Text = String.Empty;
                    loginPassword.Text = String.Empty;
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Success");
                    break;
                }
                //If not, then show this message.
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username/Password incorrect");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 


    }
}
```

Comment: how are you exposing the email variable.. is it local to another methods scope..? doesn't look like you're passing in email or `ref email`

Comment: use the debugger and step thru the code and you will see where email has a `""` or `string.Empty` value

Comment: @DJKRAZE I just did that and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: are you familiar with the term `global variable, local variable public, static, protected etc.. come on now my earlier comment lends you all of the hints that you need .. try assigning / storing the email value outside of the local method better yet.. create a property and access / assign it that way..

Comment: Yes I am familiar with the terms. I am studying programming atm. OI found the issue. It's 3 am here and I think I'm just tired. That's why I missed something. Had to do this `string email;
        private void AddUser(string username, string password, string confirmPass, string email)`

Answer (score 0):

The method AddUser receives the variable email. This is a parameter and thus it is a local variable visible only inside the method AddUser. No other methods could see or use it unless you pass the variable as a parameter or assign it to a global variable (not recommended)

```
 private void AddUser(string username, string password, string confirmPass, string email)
```

So you need to pass that variable to the HashPass method

```
.... in AddUser .....
else
{
    loginsDataSet.LoginsRow newUserRow = loginsDataSet.Logins.NewLoginsRow();
    string EncryptedPass = HashPass(password, email);
    ....
} 
...

public string HashPass(string password, string anEmailAddress)
{
    SHA256 sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

    //compute hash from the bytes of text
    sha.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password + anEmailAddress));  

    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. I tried that but then I get this error. No overload for Method 'HashPass' takes 1 arguments.

Comment: Did you pass the second argument email in the call to HashPass inside the AddUser method?

Comment: Yes I did. I did exactly what you said earlier today as well but I had no luck so I just decided to post the original error here.

Comment: how do we know that you did exactly that.. can you post the code and show what you are passing as well as calling..

Comment: This seems really strange. The error message clearly says that you are calling HashPass passing only one parameter when more are expected. So I suppose you have changed the HashPass definition to receive the two parameters but forget to change the call to HashPass inside the AddUser method. Doesn't seem possible another explanation. In any case double clicking on the error message will show you the point where this error occurs.

Comment: @JancovanHeerden you are using that `HashPass` method not only in `AddUser`, but at least in `loginButton_Click` as well. Look for all usages and change them accordingly

Comment: Yes I am familiar with the terms. I am studying programming atm. OI found the issue. It's 3 am here and I think I'm just tired. That's why I missed something. Had to do this `string email;
        private void AddUser(string username, string password, string confirmPass, string email)`